# Is there a way to convert a XML from a URL to strings.xml before building in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, url, android-studio

I want to convert a XML from a URL to localised strings.xml files. I want to do this before/while building the app in android studio. I am not sure if this is possible and how this should be done. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: i think you can do that by adding a `task` maybe to the `gradle` file, where it calls a `.bat` or `.sh` script file, that in turn download and store the `strings.xml` file in the `/values/` folder, this task can be executed while `release` or other tasks are executed i am not sure how this can be done "exactly" but logic-wise i think it's good approach :)

Comment: check this http://www.michel-kraemer.com/gradle-download-task-download-files-with-progress

Comment: I'll check it out. maybe this is what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. Resources in *values* folder can't be modified/created at runtime.

But to serve your purpose, you can download the xml from server first time when your app starts, and then store the strings in a global static class. Something like this :

```
public class Constants {

final public static String .....
.......
```

Comment: OP does not mean at runtime `before/while building the app in android studio`

Comment: he needs the xml from a url. If he means before building, then he can simply enter the values manually. If not that, he needs to download the xml at runtime.

Comment: `in android studio` is clear enough to eliminate `runtime` i think OP does not want to do that manually, just my thought :)

Comment: At runtime is option B :) I want to get it from a url so that i don't have to add it manually in the resources. This is because we want to have one xml with string for Android and iOS

Comment: @Yazan : hmm, I thought he's asking only at runtime. Anyways, your comment above looks like a probable solution if he has to do it that way :)